# RPM + Build RPM in order to create KIT

Tags: linux

I create some scripts under my Linux machine RedHat-Linux-OS-5.3

the following scripts home directory is /root/dir

And the scripts are:

```
/root/dir/rfg.sh
/root/dir/ener.pl
/root/dir/wnr.sh
```

And some lib files are under /lib as the following

```
/lib/lib1.so    
/lib/lib2.so
/lib/lib3.so
```

my question I want to create RPM that include my scripts and my lib files !

For example

After  I performed (rpm installation) :

```
rpm -i SOME_RPM.rpm
```

All scripts will be created under /root/dir     directory (include directory creation)

And all  my lib files will created under /lib    directory

Please advice how to create this RPM hopefully it will be step by step (because I read some documents regarding RPM Build package, and it’s hard to understand them

Answer (score 1):

The most basic bit is that you need the rpmbuild tool and you need to write a spec file. I have the following script that takes a spec file and a tree as it would look installed on the target machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

SPECFILE=$1
shift
SOURCEDIR=$1

BASEDIR=/usr/src/rpm/BUILD
[ -e ${BASEDIR} ] || BASEDIR=/usr/src/redhat/BUILD

BASENAME=$(grep -E '^Name:' $SPECFILE | awk '{ print $2 }')
VERSION=$(grep -E '^Version:' $SPECFILE | awk '{ print $2 }')
RELEASE=$(grep -E '^Release:' $SPECFILE | awk '{ print $2 }')
BUILDROOT=${BASEDIR}/${BASENAME}-${VERSION}-${RELEASE}

rm -rf ${BUILDROOT}
cp -r ${SOURCEDIR} ${BUILDROOT}

export SOURCEDIR BUILDROOT

rpmbuild --buildroot=${BUILDROOT} -bb $SPECFILE
```

For details on spec files, see RPM spec specification.

Comment: how to build the spec file regarding my example

Comment: what you mean about rpmbuild tool ?

Comment: Google will happily answer both those queries, I'm sure. For writing RPM specs particularly, you need a lot more information than can be readily supplied in a stackexchange post.